# Unable to access S3 data using Spark 2.2

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I get a lot of data uploaded to an S3 bucket that I want so analyze/visualize using Spark and Zeppelin. Yet, I am still stuck at loading data from S3.

I did some reading in order to get this together and spare me gory details. I am using the docker container [p7hb/docker-spark](https://hub.docker.com/r/p7hb/docker-spark/) as Spark installation and my basic test for reading data from S3 is derived [from here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_s3.html):

1. I start the container and a master and a slave process within. I can validate this works by looking at the Spark Master WebUI, exposed on port 8080. This page does list the worker and keeps a log of all my failed attempts under the headline "Completed Applications". All of those are in the state `FINISHED`.
2. I open a `bash` inside that container and do the following:

   a) export the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, as suggested [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).

   b) start `spark-shell`. In order to access S3 one seems to need to load some extra packages. Browsing through SE I found especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968326/accessing-s3-using-s3a-protocol-from-spark-using-hadoop-version-2-7-2), which teaches me, that I can use the `--packages` parameter to load said packages. Essentially I run `spark-shell --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.15,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.5`(, for arbitrary combinations of versions).

   c) I run the following  code

   `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")`
   `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")`
   `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")`

   `val sonnets=sc.textFile("s3a://my-bucket/my.file")`

   `val counts = sonnets.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)`

And then I get all kinds of different Error messages, depending on the versions I choose in 2b).

I suppose there is nothing wrong with 2a), b/c I get the error message `Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain` if I don't supply those. [This is a known error new users seem to make.](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1324)

While trying to solve the issue, I pick more or less random versions  from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk) and [there](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws) for the two extra packages. Somewhere on SE I read that hadoop-aws:2.7 is supposed to be the right choice, because Spark 2.2 is based on Hadoop 2.7. Supposedly one needs to use aws-java-sdk:1.7 with that version of hadoop-aws.

Whatever! I tried thefollowing combinations

- `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1`, which yields the common Bad Request 400 error.
  Many problems can lead to that error, my attempt as described above containseverything I was able to find on this page. The description above contains `s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` as endpoint, while other places use `s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`. According to [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region), both endpoint names are supposed to work. I did try both.
- `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.15,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.5`, which are the most recent micro versions in either case, I get the error message `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.<init>(Lcom/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3;Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecuto
  r;)V`
- `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.275,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.5`, I also get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.<init>(Lcom/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3;Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor;)V`
- `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.275,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.1`, I get `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation`
- `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.275,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.3`, I also get `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation`
- `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.8.12,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.8.3`, I also get `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation`
- `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.275,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.9.0`, I also get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics`

And, for completeness sake, when I don't provide the `--packages` parameter, I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found`.

Currently nothing seems to work. Yet, there are so many Q/As on this topic, who knows what's the way du jour of doing this. This is all in local mode, so there is virtually no other source of error. My method of accessing S3 must be wrong. How is it done correctly?

---

### Edit 1:

So I put another day into this, without any actual progress. As far as I can tell, starting from Hadoop 2.6, Hadoop doesn't have built in support for S3 anymore, but it as to be loaded through additional libraries, which are not part of Hadoop and entirely managed by itself. Besides all the clutter, the library I ultimately want seems to be `hadoop-aws`. It has a webpage [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) andit carries what I would call authoritative information:

> The versions of hadoop-common and hadoop-aws must be identical.

The important thing about this information is, that `hadoop-common` actually does ship with a Hadoop installation. Every Hadoop installation has a corresponding jar file, so this is a solid starting point. My containers have a file `/usr/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar` so it is fair to assume 2.7.3 is the version I need for `hadoop-aws`.

After that it gets murky. Hadoop versions 2.7.x have something going on internally, so that they are not compatible with more recent versions of `aws-java-sdk`, which is a library required by `hadoop-aws`. The Internet is full of advice to use version 1.7.4, [for example here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12420), but [other comments](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12267)  suggest to using version 1.7.14 for 2.7.x.

So I did another run using `hadoop-aws:2.7.3` and `aws-java-sdk:1.7.x`, with `x` ranging from 4 to 14. No results whatsover, I always end up with error 400, Bad Request.

My Hadoop installation ships `joda-time` 2.9.4. I read the problem was resolved with Hadoop 2.8. I suppose I will just go ahead and build my own docker containers with more recent versions.

---

### Edit 2

Moved to Hadoop 2.8.3. It just works now. Turns out you don't even have to mess around with JARs at all. Hadoop ships with what are supposed to be working JARs for accessing AWS S3. They are hidden in `${HADOOP_HOME}/share/hadoop/tools/lib` and not added to the classpath by default. I simply load the JARS in that directory, execute my code as stated above and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing and matching AWS SDK JARs with anything else is an exercise in futility, as you've discovered. You need the version of the AWS JARs Hadoop was built with, and the version of Jackson AWS was built with. Oh, and don't try mixing any of (different amazon-* JARs, different hadoop-* JARs, different jackson-* JARs); they all go in lock-sync.

For Spark 2.2.0 and Hadoop 2.7, use AWS 1.7.4 artifacts, and make sure that if you are on Java 8, that Joda time is > 2.8.0, such as 2.9.4. That can lead to 400 "bad auth problems".

Otherwise, try [Troubleshooting S3A](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md)

Comment: And how do I find out with which AWS JARs Hadoop was built with and the version of Jackson AWS was built with?

Comment: I'd look at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws